# Counting unique numbers of tasks, when another cell range contains a random amount of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have a spreadsheet that has many columns, however I'm needing help with developing a formula that encompasses only two of those columns. The sheet itself is setup like this:

```
Date        Task
6/1/18      Row
6/1/18      Spot
6/1/18      Row
6/2/18      Spot
6/2/18      Spot
6/3/18      Row
6/3/18      Row
6/3/18      Row
6/3/18      Spot
...etc
```

Based on the above values, I am trying to figure out how many times Row appears in the "Task" list, however only counting it for unique dates. So on 6/1 we had Row twice, however it should only count as once, since we only spent one day doing the Row task. On 6/2, Row is not there at all, so our total amount of days doing the Row task is still at 1. On 6/3, Row was done 3 different times, however it should only count as one day, bringing the total amount of days we have worked on Row to 2.

Likewise, if we were to calculate for "Spot" then the total number of days worked on "Spot" would be 3. (This would be a separate cell value, but same premise, therefore same formula.)

I don't have the slightest idea how to get this formula even started. I know quite a bit about Excel, however my knowledge does not cover this specific issue, and I am not sure where to even start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sounds like a job for countif(s).

Comment: So, when I do a "=COUNTIF(D:D,"ROW")" formula, it definitely gives me the amount of times ROW is used in the D column. My issue, though, is what I am unable to comprehend correctly, and that is only choosing a cell in the D range as counted if the date to the left of it is not repeated. It's so far outside of my grasp, at the moment, that I can't really explain it in one sentence correctly haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my bookmark for counting unique rows with a criteria: [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria)

The formula that will work for you is:

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$10=D1,MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))`

This is an array formula and will need to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I was needing done. I did not know a thing about Excel array formulas, so I did not even think to search for one. Thank you for your insight! This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

[image: Picture of excel]

Column A and B are your columns
Cell C1 in C column (and all else): =A2&B2
D1 is simply 1
D2 cell is (drag that formula down also): =IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1, C2)>0, 0, 1)
H1 cell is: =SUMIF($B$1:$B$200, G1, $D$1:$D$200)
G1 is "Row"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a reason that D1 needs to be input statically? I'm looking more for something that handles everything automatically. The dudes in the field are very, very non-tech-savvy, so if they have to do anything other than select a drop-down, it is going to throw them off. These formulas look absolutely promising though! Especially the =A2&B2 section, where I'm getting unique values into one column, instead of having to find a unique column based on another column.

Comment: In column D you can have something like this: =IF(ROW(D1)>1, IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1, C2)>0, 0, 1), 1) , if you want formula to be same in all fields in D column :)

Comment: Thank you! The array formula posted by Glitch_Doctor was the one-line answer I was looking for. Your insight, though, was helpful, and allowed me to learn a little more and expand on the COUNTIF and IF statements. Thanks for offering up some info!

Comment: No problem, glad I've helped.